# Holy moly Wikipedia references

Tags: discussion

This question has more answers with references to wikipedia than I've seen combined everywhere on SO:

[Is Method Overloading considered polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400284/is-method-overloading-considered-polymorphism)

This seems wrong. Should something be done about this?

Comment: Why is it wrong to have lots of references to Wikipedia?  Or lots references in general?

Comment: @StephenC A stackoverflow answer that basically just links to wikipedia is very unhelpful. Would prefer a more authoritative type answer. And as you mentioned down below, they are basically opinions. Just bad bad bad.

Comment: There are no truly authoritative answers to any questions about design.  Design is *all* a matter of opinion.  Ditto most questions about terminology ... since there are no authorities for most terminology.  (Exceptions are terminology defined in the context of a specification.)

Comment: I count 6 links to [wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org), 7 if you include a deleted comment that mentions [wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org). That's not very many references to [wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org)! if you really want to talk about [wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org), just take a look at this comment where I mention [wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org) way more times than [wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org) has ever been mentioned in a comment about [wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org). Come to think of it... [wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org)

Comment: I find Wikipedia to be generally authoritative.  Except on the topics I know a lot about.  Something was done about it, not all of the answers use Wikipedia to make them sound credible.  The better ones.  Don't forget to vote.

Answer (score 7):

It's not really a good question. There's no central authority who decides what is and is not "polymorphism". So given a not very good question, it's hardly a surprise that the answers might not be the best either.

Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: In fact, there is a case for closing the Question as "requires an opinion based answer".

Comment: -1 The term “polymorphism” is clearly defined in the area of type systems and programming languages. The Wikipedia article seems to get it right. Academic definitions are found in Pierce 2002 “Types and Programming Languages”, Cardelli & Wegner 1985 “On understanding types, data abstraction, and polymorphism”, and originally Strachey 1967 “Fundamental Concepts in Programming Languages”. I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @amon - it really looks a lot like a question about semantics.  Regardless of whether or not there is a clear definition, how are questions about what words mean on topic for SO? I'm open to reopening, but I'd need some convincing.